# Discrete line numbers specified individually not as range

Tags: vimscript, ex-mode, line-numbers

I was trying to find out if it is possible to give an ex command a list of lines instead of a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`:h :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3arange) it doesn't seem possible to use a list of numbers as a range.

I think that what you are looking for is the global command ([`:h :global`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3aglobal)) which applies a command on the lines matching a pattern.

If you look at [`:h /ordinary-atom`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fordinary-atom) you will see that `\%Xl` allows you to match the line number `X`. So for example if you have the following buffer:

```
foo
bar
fizz
fuzz
```

And you want to replace `f` by `F` on the first line you can do:

```
:g/\%1l/s/f/F
```

And if you want to do it on the first and third line:

```
:g/\%1l\|\%3l/s/f/F
```